# Glide no actualiza imagen cuando la cambio en mi servidor

Tags: java, android, android-glide

Parece que la imagen queda en cache e investigando un poco parece que tengo que limpiar el cache tambien trate de saltar el guardado en cache pero nada funciona raramente solo se me actualiza cuando cambio tambien el nombre pero creo que es logico ya que al encontrar un nuevo nombre si actualiza perfectamente pero si le dejo el mismo nombre y solo actualizo la imagen se queda con la anterior y tambien se actualiza solo reinstalando lo cual tambien es logico tratandose de una imagen que queda en cache estos son los metodos que he utilizado pero no se que mas podria hacer para poder evitar el cachge:

Usar signature

```
Glide.with(cContext).load(categorias).centerCrop().signature(new ObjectKey(UUID.randomUUID().toString())).into(categoriaViewHolder.imageView);
```

Saltar el cache

```
Glide.with(cContext).load(categorias).centerCrop().skipMemoryCache(true).into(categoriaViewHolder.imageView);
```

Borrar el cache

```
Glide.with(cContext).clear(categoriaViewHolder.imageView);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Para poder limpiar el caché y evitar mantenga la misma imagen usando Glide, usa la propiedad, `skipMemoryCache(true)`** :

```
Glide.with(cContext).load(categorias).centerCrop().skipMemoryCache(true).signature(new ObjectKey(UUID.randomUUID().toString())).into(categoriaViewHolder.imageView);
```

Comment: Por alguna razon StringSignature no es reconocido en mi adaptador e investigando al respecto debía cambiarlo por ObjectKey para hacerlo funcionar

Comment: Una disculpa, necesitas otras dependencias,pero mejor usa ObjectKey pero agrega la propiedad skipMemoryCache(true), actualice la respuesta. @AdielMoran

Comment: Gracias Jorge agregando skipMemoryCache(true) al codigo ya me funciona perfectamente

Comment: Excelente @AdielMoran , saludos!